# I have been learning python 3.5, and trying to get a string to reprint a user input variable?

Tags: python, string, user-input

```
print ("how old are you??"),
age = input()
print("How tall are you"),
height = input()
print("How much do you weigh"),
weight = input()

print("So, you're '%r' old, '%r' tall and weigh '%r' ") % ('age, height weight')
```

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'str

Comment: There is a comma missing in between height, and weight, and remove the comma after the prints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't put your variables in quotes. Instead of

```
print("So, you're '%r' old, '%r' tall and weigh '%r' ") % ('age, height weight')
```

put

```
print("So, you're '%r' old, '%r' tall and weigh '%r' " % (age, height weight))
```

Comment: That's true, but the error is actually caused by another issue in the code. Basically the `%` is applied to the return value of `print`, which is `None`, and the tuple.

Answer (score 0):

As a bit of a fellow noob. A simple way of achieving this is asking your question while assigning the variable

```
age = input("how old are you??")
height = input("How tall are you")
weight = input("How much do you weigh")

print("So, you're", age, "years old", height, "tall and weigh", weight)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print ("how old are you??"),
age = input()
print("How tall are you"),
height = input()
print("How much do you weigh"),
weight = input()

print("So, you're '%r' old, '%r' tall and weigh '%r' " %(age, height, weight))
```

If you put the variables in quotes it becomes a string. Also make sure each variable has a comma after it if you're going to add another variable.